# how to save QR Code number in database Sqlite

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a number and i´d like to transforme it in qr code and save into my database SQLite. Then i have to show this qr code on the screen and i don´t know how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to store numbers in the database and generate QR codes from them in the client using js tool like https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ ?

Comment: Also please provide an example what are you trying to do in code.

Comment: I got it. The question can close.